# CenterPoint of Polygon in ArcEngine .Net 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, polygon, .net, point-in-polygon

I am currently trying to get the center point of a polygon. In GIS, i can see the "x" mark in the center of the polygon, but I do not know how to get it from the IPolygon object.

I tried getting the enevelope and getting the midpoint from that but that didn't work out very well, as getting the envelope does not always ensure to get the midpoitn where marked "x".

Thanks and Regards,
Kev

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for the centroid?

You could use [iArea:Centroid](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/ComponentHelp/esriGeometry/IArea_Centroid.htm) to obtain the centroid of the geometry (may not fall inside of the area if the geometry

Or

you could use [iArea:LabelPoint](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/ComponentHelp/esriGeometry/IArea_LabelPoint.htm) which is similar to centroid but guaranteed to fall inside of the area of the geometry.

However, I am pretty sure that the "X" you are referring to is obtained from the envelope of the geometry. Since [iEnvelope](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/ComponentHelp/esriGeometry/IEnvelope.htm) does not have a "center" property you may need to calculate it: ((XMin + XMax) / 2, (YMin + YMax) / 2).